# How many bestiary entries are there in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have unlocked 67 entries so far and I am at level 22 taking my time finishing the game. I am wondering how many are there in total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you count them. If you sum up every single entry (including every Drowner and Endriga subtype), I would say about 110: http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Creatures+and+Monsters